# SQL Server : no data from a query which should return data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running a SQL query on SQL Server which logically should return some data, but it doesn't:

```
SELECT 
    D.NAME DATABASE_NAME, T.NAME TABLE_NAME, I.NAME INDEX_NAME,
    C.NAME COLUMN_NAME
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (NULL, NULL, NULL , NULL, 'LIMITED') AS XXX
INNER JOIN 
    SYS.DATABASES AS D ON D.DATABASE_ID = XXX.DATABASE_ID
INNER JOIN 
    SYS.TABLES AS T ON T.OBJECT_ID = XXX.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN 
    SYS.INDEXES AS I ON I.OBJECT_ID = T.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN 
    SYS.INDEX_COLUMNS IC ON IC.OBJECT_ID = I.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN 
    SYS.COLUMNS AS C ON C.OBJECT_ID = IC.OBJECT_ID
WHERE 
    1=1
ORDER BY 
    D.NAME, T.NAME
```

Running just this bit outputs lots of data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (NULL, NULL, NULL , NULL, 'LIMITED')
```

So why doesn't the more complex query work?

Comment: It returns a load of rows for me. However, the actual data it returns doesn't look useful: I think one of your joins is incorrect. Looking at the query, every table uses the same object_id (except sys.databases) according to your joins which doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: check what database are you running it on. I ran this on master database and it returned no rows. it works on my own database. BTW, when joining index and columns, you need to add one more condition IC.index_id = I.index_id

Comment: Well, the whole point of this is to get all possible indexes on that SQL server and display them by DB/TB/INDEX. Not sure what you mean by adding a condition like 'IC.index_id = I.index_id' ?

Comment: In addition to what @FLICKER said, are you looking for the columns covered by an the index? As at the moment it looks like you're showing all columns in every table which has an index of any sort - you probably want to use `AND C.column_id = ic.column_id` on the join to `SYS.COLUMNS`

Comment: OK, is there a way to get all tables from all databases at once? I can get the database info from sys.databases, but sys.tables, doesn't seem to work the same.

Comment: You **cannot** get data from **all** databases on a server by using one particular database's `sys` catalog views. These catalog views are **per database** - not global across the whole server

Comment: @robertalks Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you're looking to output, along with keeping your current attempt. It saves digging around in the comments to find out what someone is after rather than the question equivalent of `fix this query` without knowing what you want!

Comment: @Bridge, I know what I want, I didn't know you cant get all tables for all databases. Thats why the query doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not joining up things correctly...

For example, index_columns has an object_id (for the table) and an index_id (for the index). Note that the indexid is not globally unique but unique only within the context of that table (i.e. object_id) so you need to join on both columns when you pull in the index_columns.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT 
    TOP 50 
      t.name as tablename, 
      i.name as indexname, 
      c.name as columnname, 
      ic.key_ordinal, ic.is_descending_key
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
    ON i.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic
    ON ic.object_id = t.object_id
    AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
    AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
ORDER by t.name, i.name, c.name, ic.key_ordinal
```